# Java replace Japanese characters with \\p{Katakana} regular expression

Tags: java, regex, replaceall, katakana

i have followed that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809176/regular-expressions-regex-in-japanese)

and the user "slevithan" offer using `\p{Katakana}`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "マイポケット (1).csv";
    str=    str.replaceAll(  "[\\p{Katakana}]", "_");//.replaceAll("\\p{Z}", "_");
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

but i get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown character property name {Katakana} near index 12
[\p{Katakana}]
```

i am working with java 8 .
what is the correct syntax for checking Japanese characters with String replaceAll ?

Comment: Did you compile with  `javac -encoding UTF-8` ?

Comment: or try `str = str.replaceAll(  "[\\p{InKatakana}]", "_");`

Comment: that letter ポ is not recognized as katakana which it is.
can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution was with this Regular-Expression when working with negative look-ahead .

```
str.replaceAll("(?![-,.,/p{Han}/p{Hiragana}/p{Katakana},\\p{IsAlphabetic}\\p{IsDigit}])[\\p{Punct}\\s]", "_");
```

Answer (score -1):

i needed to support both English and Japanese letters

that regular expression did the trick:

```
str.replaceAll(  "[/p{Han}/p{Hiragana}/p{Katakana}&&[^\\.^\\p{IsAlphabetic}^\\p{IsDigit}^-]]", "_");
```

Comment: `[\\p{InKatakana}\\w]` will also work if you want English character

Comment: and why are you using `^` three times?

Comment: the use of /p its working in java 8 - which is exactly like writing \\p

Comment: @rock321987 what if i want to support all possible languages ?

Comment: @rock321987 notice that  /p{Katakana} and \\p{InKatakana}
are not the same  \\p{InKatakana}  does not support the letter ポ
which   /p{Katakana}  does support it

Comment: for supporting all possible language, simply use `\\p{L}`

Comment: The forward slash does not have a special meaning in Java regular expressions. For example, the two regular expressions `[/p{Katakana}]` and `[{}/Kaknpt]` are equivalent.